Prometheus Service Discovery for Tailscale client metrics
Question: Is there a definitive mechanism in Tailscale API that enables me to enumerate the list of devices on a tailnet that expose client metrics?
Tailscale client metrics are useful and -- for Tailscale devices (not all machines [vernacular?]), I'm able to browse tailnet devices' IP(v4) :5252/metrics endpoints.
I've written a basic Prometheus HTTP Service Discovery mechanism using Tailscale's API (Go SDK) to enumerate devices (/tailnet/{tailnet}/devices) but this method returns all devices including tailscaled which may publish the metrics endpoints (:5252/metrics), and arbitrary services (e.g. Kubernetes services) that are published on the tailnet.
The problem is that, Prometheus Service Discovery expects uniformity|conformity in targets scraped this way and, because I have a mixture of tailscaled and non-services presenting as Devices on the tailnet, those not publishing metrics on :5252/metrics, are (correctly) reported as down.
This is undesirable; I'd prefer discovering only devices that publish metrics.
Tailscale's Device type does not appear to provide a mechanism to disambiguate between these types of device.
The admin console includes Services which don't appear to be part of the public API but do include e.g. tailscaled services on port 5252 which, if I could infer would, I think permit me to filter the list of devices (for Service Discovery) to those that publish client metrics.

Unable to find a solution using Tailscale's API.
My hack is to filter the list of devices by some test that identifies and caches those exposing client metrics.
Cacheing assumes that:

once a device exposes client metrics, it will continue to do so;
a device not exposing client metrics, is unlikely to start doing so.

Alternative tests:

Successfully opening a socket on a device's :5252
HEAD'ing a device's :5252/metrics

